# Set a location that an element can be draggable at

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a jquery function that allows an element to be draggable and resizeable and it works fine. What I wanted to add to it was to set a location in which the element can be draggable and resizable at. To be more specific I wanted to make my element draggable between the space in 2 lines (v1 and vh) in my code. Is there any way to achieve this? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```js
    $(".box").mouseup(function () {
        $(this).find('iframe').fadeIn('slow');
    }).mousedown(function () {
        $(this).find('iframe').hide();
    });

    $(function () {
        $(".box")
            .resizable()
            .draggable();
    });
```

```css
.box {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 32%;
    height: 30%;
    background-color: #2b2d2f;
    color: black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1%;    
}

.box h4{
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align:center;   
}

.vl {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5%;
    top: 0;
    background-color: red;
    width: 2.5px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.vh {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 75%;
    background-color: red;
    height: 2.5px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
 
</head>
<body>

<div class="box">
<h4>box</h4>
</div>

    <div class="vl">
    </div>
    <div class="vh">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `draggable()` jQueryUI component has a `containment` parameter. One of its signatures allows you to provide 4 co-ordinates which equate to the bounding box the draggable element should be restricted to.

To calculate this you can retrieve the `left` and `top` of the vertical and horizontal lines respectively, subtracting the width/height of the `.box`. Try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let $box = $('.box');
  let $vl = $('.vl');
  let $vh = $('.vh');

  $box
    .resizable()
    .draggable({
      containment: [
        8, // default body padding, amend as necessary
        8, // default body padding, amend as necessary
        Math.ceil(parseFloat($vl.css('left'))) - Math.floor(parseFloat($box.width())),
        Math.ceil(parseFloat($vh.css('top'))) - Math.floor(parseFloat($box.height()))
      ]
    });
});
```

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 32%;
  height: 30%;
  background-color: #2b2d2f;
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1%;
}

.box h4 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.vl {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5%;
  top: 0;
  background-color: red;
  width: 2.5px;
  height: 90%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.vh {
  position: absolute;
  top: 75%;
  background-color: red;
  height: 2.5px;
  width: 95%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<div class="box">
  <h4>box</h4>
</div>
<div class="vl"></div>
<div class="vh"></div>
```

Comment: But after you resize the box element it won't be contained anymore?@Rory McCrossan

Comment: If that's a requirement you'll need to update the `containment` setting every time the box is resized.

Answer (score 1):

One  approach is wrap the box in a container that fits within the area you want and use `containment: "parent"`

```js
function getContainerDimensions() {
  const buffer = 6 // used in demo to prevent borders overlap
  return {
    width: $('.vl').offset().left - buffer,
    height: $('.vh').offset().top - buffer
  }
}

$(function() {
  const $cont = $('<div id="container">').css(getContainerDimensions())
  $(".box").wrap($cont)
    .resizable({containment: "parent"})
    .draggable({containment: "parent"});
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}

#container {
  border: 2px solid green
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 32%;
  height: 30%;
  background-color: #2b2d2f;
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1%;
}

.box h4 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.vl {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5%;
  top: 0;
  background-color: red;
  width: 2.5px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.vh {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 75%;
  background-color: red;
  height: 2.5px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

</head>

<body>

  <div class="box">
    <h4>box</h4>
  </div>

  <div class="vl">
  </div>
  <div class="vh">
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```